# Dismiss UIAlertController after few seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I need to show a box without submit button but let it disappear after 3 second. Is it possible to attach any timeout?

```
  UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please wait, checking your PAID INVOICE, to allow the service."
                                message:"...waiting..."
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES 
  completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

May below code will do the work:

```
UIAlertController *alert=   [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please wait, checking your PAID INVOICE, to allow the service."
                                message:"...waiting..."
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES 
  completion:nil]; 


dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

            //Dismissed
        }];

});
```

Comment: this lead to duplicates code, if the function is required multiple times

Comment: Nice idea, but if you should probably add the dispatch/dismiss code to the `presentViewController` `completion:` block

Answer (score 5):

Following on from @RonakChaniyara's answer, this adds a test that the alert is still presented (if using with an alert that has a button to dismiss, for example).

```
[presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion: {

    // Dispatch 3 seconds after alert presented
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Check that alert is still presented
        if self.presentedViewController == alert {
            // Dismiss if it is
            [self.dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{    
                //Dismissed
            }];    
        }
    });
}];
```

and in Swift…

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Wait", message: "…waiting…", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

present(alert, animated: true) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) { [weak self] in
        guard self?.presentedViewController == alert else { return }

        self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try it like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),     dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: this lead to duplicates code, if the function is required multiple times

Answer (score 4):

add `performSelector` with  your alertController and create your UIAlertController object as gobally

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(hideAlertView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

-(void)hideAlertView{
 [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  // or use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:alert completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to dismiss your `UIAlertController`. You need to declare `UIAlertController` globally.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

Your selector method

```
-(void)removeAlert{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:alert completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:
For Objective-C

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertController:) withObject:alertController afterDelay:3.0];
    }];

    - (void)dismissAlertController:(UIAlertController *)alertController {
        [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

For Swift 3

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    present(alertController, animated: true) { 
        self.perform(#selector(ViewController.dismissAlertController(alertController:)), with: alertController, afterDelay: 3.0)
    }

    internal func dismissAlertController(alertController: UIAlertController) {
        alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to subclass `UIAlertController`, to your own class, and in the `viewDidAppear`, add a `NSTimer` to dismiss automatically.

Don't forget to `invalidate` the timer and to release it in the `viewDidDisappear` method

Comment: Terrible idea… you're massively overcomplicating things!

Comment: Why that ? Subclassing is overcomplicated ? Having reusable code too ? And testability ?

Comment: Good answer, but a code example would be a nice bonus.